# javascript does not work on firefox (working fine on other)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

as in title, i have problem with javascript. I put javascript on my jsp page. On chrome and IE it works fine, but on firefox does not. I haven no idea what is wrong, and what i have to do. Not only my firefox does not want to run it, I have tested it on other. 
Any idea?

```
                <script type ="text/javascript">
                var x = '<%=best%>';
                var y = '<%=worst%>';

                CountDownTimer(x, 'countdown');

                function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
                {
                    var end = new Date(dt);
                    var y = '<%=worst%>';
                    var til = new Date(y);

                    var _second = 1000;
                    var _minute = _second * 60;
                    var _hour = _minute * 60;
                    var _day = _hour * 24;
                    var timer;


                    function showRemaining() {
                        var now = new Date();
                        var distance = end - now;
                        var stil = til - now;
                        var exit = distance + 300000;


                        if (distance < 0 && stil > 0) {

                            clearInterval(timer);
                            document.getElementById(id).textContent  = 'Videokonsultacja jest aktywna. ';
                            document.getElementById(id).textContent  += 'Prosze wcisnąć przycisk "połącz. ';
                            return;
                        } else if (stil === 0) {
                            location.reload();
                        } else if (stil < 0) {

                            clearInterval(timer);
                            document.getElementById(id).textContent  += 'Konsultacja juz się odbyła. ';
                            return;
                        }



                        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);



                        document.getElementById(id).textContent  = 'Do konsultacji pozostało ' + days + 'dni ';
                        document.getElementById(id).textContent  += hours + 'godzin ';
                        document.getElementById(id).textContent  += minutes + 'minut ';
                        document.getElementById(id).textContent  += seconds + 'sekund';
                    }

                    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
                }

            </script>
            <div id="countdown"></div>
```

On the top of jsp i have:

```
    <%  String data = request.getParameter("event_start_date");  %>
    <%  String end = request.getParameter("event_end_date");  %>
```

To get parameters from previesly page.

nextly:

```
 <%
                String target = data;
                String tar = end;

                String dodaj = ":00";
                String nowe = target + dodaj;
                String ostatnia = tar + dodaj;
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                Date result = df.parse(nowe);
                Date koniec = df.parse(ostatnia);

                String best = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm").format(result);
                String worst = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm").format(koniec);
            %>
```

To convert String to Date format

Comment: What does the console say ? Some log would help.

Comment: please add some values for `<%=best%>` and `<%=worst%>`.

Comment: The problem is within the `x` and `y` vars: `<%=best%>` doesn't work.

Comment: Any idea? Yep, show the output from the console in FF. It knows why it wont process the script and will tell you. If you paste that error here, perhaps someone will tell you how to interpret/make use of it. ;)